# Testing mobile web in real carrier network

Tags: mobile

we have different products which are integrated with mobile carrier billing system. How can we test this remotely using any cloud services. 
I have gone through Keynote and deviceanywhere, but they have limited set of carriers. I am looking for carrier networks in Asia region which can be accessed over the cloud.

thanks in advance !

Comment: You can try Perfecto Mobile Cloud testing services, as Perfecto Mobile claims to support 99% of the carriers.   http://www.perfectomobile.com/